# Image Clipped using Rectangle Geometry not stretching

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Fill" Width="220" Height="220"  Source="{Binding ElementName=defectsList,Path=SelectedItem.WidgetImage, Converter={converters:StringToImageSourceConverter}}">
        <Image.Clip>
          <RectangleGeometry Rect="0 0 50 50">
          </RectangleGeometry>
        </Image.Clip>
      </Image>
```

Here, my expectation is that the image should be cut 50X50 and must be stretched to 220 X 220 and be displayed. But it is being displayed 50 X 50 leaving the remaining space blank.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to display a portion of the `Image`, you could use a `CroppedBitmap`:

```
<Image Width="220" Height="220">
    <Image.Source>
        <CroppedBitmap Source="{Binding ElementName=defectsList,Path=SelectedItem.WidgetImage, Converter={converters:StringToImageSourceConverter}}" SourceRect="0 0 50 50"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: oh cool. I also want to know how to bind Rect to  SourceRect  from inside the data template?

Comment: That's a totally different story. Please ask another question if you have another issue :)